Link on feed starts with the site URL in Drupal 9
I have created a view in Drupal 9, which is basically a feed. It lists the job items, and within each item, there is a node called <link>, which shows the job URL.
Now the problem is that the node  starts with the site URL and then the actual job link appears.
Example -
<link>https://sitename.com/%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A//JOBURL/jobs/position%22%3Ehttps%3A//JOBURL/jobs/position/%3C/a%3E</link>

I want this to be
<link>https://JOBURL/jobs/position/</link>

Any help is highly appreciated.
